# How to make a JavaScript to JQuery conversion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need a bit of help converting javascript to jquery. I'm using an accordion for a website i
I'm creating.

```
var acc = $(".accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function(){
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
  }
}
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="our-club-accordion">
      <button class="accordion">Our Goal</button>
      <div class="panel">
      </div>
      <button class="accordion">Our Mission</button>
      <div class="panel">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: @ndugger Javascript -> jQuery is cleaner....

Comment: @James The only people that think that are people that don't know the vanilla APIs, and write spaghetti jQuery.

Comment: @James That sounds like a dangerous generalization.

Comment: @ndugger it is an extreme generalization..ha However, taking into consideration that the OP said they are new to javascript and jQuery. I'm also assuming that they don't know Vanilla or any other cleaner libraries..

Comment: What did you try? Show your attempts...

Comment: @ndugger I wouldn't argue that at all. But the OP wants to know how to convert it to jQuery. I should have said that jQuery is cleaner IF you know how to use it properly. I was generalizing based off of my experience with it I suppose

Comment: @James I would never say that jQuery is cleaner; once again, if you know the vanilla APIs, you'll write MUCH cleaner and faster code. I've never seen clean jQuery, and I doubt I ever will.

Comment: Thank you all for your input! I understand some of your frustration but I am trying to learn lots of languages at once.

Comment: @ndugger hmm. Interesting. Again, I'm only comparing javascript to jQuery. I know there are plenty of libraries that write MUCH cleaner code and that I prefer to use over jQuery. But, I can generally write much cleaner code in jQuery that in javascript. Certainly there are exceptions. This is just an opinionated view. I've never used vanilla though. Definitely something I'm going to look into.

Comment: @James What he/she asked for was 'convert to jquery', but what they needed was an explanation of where they went wrong. As it stands someone else just wrote a click event handler for them that changes some classNames. This is now just a "write me some code" question and useless to anyone in the future (as there are already questions covering these topics). While attacking people for jQuery use isn't helpful, neither is complying with requests to 'convert my code to jquery" when they are so very close to doing it without.

Comment: @Luggage I didn't post that answer..

Comment: @James Yea, I didn't mean that you did.

Comment: @Luggage Oh, gotcha. I agree with ya!

Comment: @Luggage I agree with what you're saying. It's very hard to find a place which describes the conversion process of JS to JQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Seems it is that you need:

```
$('.accordion').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active').next().toggleClass('show');
});
```